# Difference in results while using .CHILDREN and .ALLMEMBERS in an MDX statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx, ssas-2012

I have two almost similar MDX queries, in one I am using .CHILDREN and in other .ALLMEMBERS. First one returns no rows, the second one returns two. Please help me in understanding why!

Query 1

```
select 
[Measures].[Claim As Of - Count] on 0,
[Accident Date].[Year].allmembers on 1
from [AW Cube]
where [Accident Date].[Year-Quarter-Month-Date].[Year].&[2010]
```

---2 rows

Query 2

```
select 
[Measures].[Claim As Of - Count] on 0,
[Accident Date].[Year].children on 1
from [AW Cube]
where [Accident Date].[Year-Quarter-Month-Date].[Year].&[2010]
```

--NO rows

---- Claim As Of - Count
--All 637,350
--2010 637,350

Just to add up, 
AccidentDate is one of the Dimensions in my Cube [AW Cube]. Year is a natural hierarchy while [Year-Quarter-Month-Date] is an user defined hierarchy. [Year-Quarter-Month-Date] is created in the below way: Year-->Month--->Quarter--->Date. So 'years' can be obtained by doing [Accident Date].[Year-Quarter-Month-Date].[Year].members and also [Accident Date].[Year].MEMBERS.

Comment: Will no knight come forth to rescue the poor soul? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, got the answer myself. Actually every `.CHILDREN` gets internally translated to `.CURRENTMEMBER.CHILDREN` Now, `[Accident Date].[Year].&[2010]` is the corresponding value for the slicer on user defined hierarchy. Here, `[Accident Date].[Year].CHILDREN` actually gets translated to `[Accident Date].[Year].&[2010].CHILDREN` which is basically an empty set. Hence, Voila! The empty result set!