# MDX syntax: Difference between Period.Financial Year.Financial Year and Period.Financial Year.Children?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube

We have a cube called Revenue.

```
SELECT
    {[Measures].[Billable Hours]} on columns,
     [Period].[Financial Year].**[Financial Year]** on rows
FROM [REVENUE];

SELECT 
    {[Measures].[Billable Hours]} on columns,
     [Period].[Financial Year].**Children** on rows
FROM [REVENUE];
```

There is a dimension "Period", with I guess the attribute hierarchy is Financial Year? and if I want rows like 2012, 2013, 2014, I have to say either [Period].[Financial Year].**Children** or [Period].[Financial Year].**[Financial Year]**. To get [Period].[Financial Year].[Financial Year], in `SSMS`, I opened that attribute hierarchy, dragged the little dot under Members that says Financial Year, and that's what it gave me.

Both ways get me the same result. So just wondering,

1. is .Children more preferable, or is it just preference?
2. Also, if one were to "diagram" [Period].[Financial Year].**[Financial Year]**, would it be "Dimension.Level.Member"? so is [Financial Year]/Children a member, or how does one diagram that "whole thing" and
3. what should I call that whole thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsure what you mean by "diagram".

Both of you column expressions are, I think, short-cuts.

This

```
[Period].[Financial Year].[Financial Year]
```

Is short for this

```
[Period].[Financial Year].[Financial Year].MEMBERS
```

And this:

```
[Period].[Financial Year].CHILDREN
```

Is short for this:

```
[Period].[Financial Year].[All].CHILDREN
```

---

(To rewind a bit)

All attribute hierarchies have two levels - an all level and a leaf level. The all level only has a single member [All] which in turn has members - the leaves. There is also the leaf level, made up of the leaves.

So it looks like you've tapped into these two different levels of the hierarchy `[Financial Year]`.

---

Which should you use? Sometimes I don't believe it matters. In more complex scenarios maybe which you use will have an impact on performance.

Sometimes you might like to grab the All member and the leaves - then you can do something like the following:

```
SELECT 
    {[Measures].[Billable Hours]} on columns,
     [Period].[Financial Year].MEMBERS on rows
FROM [REVENUE];
```

This should return a set that includes the All member?

---

Q2

This `[Period].[Financial Year].[Financial Year]` is `Dimension.Hierarchy.Level`. The hierarchy's All member is not accessible at this level.

---

To repeat Greg Galloway's comment:

> `[Period].[Financial Year].CHILDREN` assumes the `All` member is the
>   default member and the current member in the context and won't work as
>   intended in all contexts.
>
> Preferable to use `[Period].[Financial Year].[All].CHILDREN` or
>   `[Period].[Financial Year].[Financial Year].MEMBERS`

Comment: I prefer [Period].[Financial Year].[Financial Year].MEMBERS as I think it is most unambiguous. I believe [Period].[Financial Year].CHILDREN assumes the All member is the default member and the current coordinate so your mileage may vary. But I agree I see that a lot.

Comment: I'm reading MDX Step by Step, ran to page 74, and it explained "in an attribute hierarchy, **the leaf level of the hierarchy is named the same as the attribute-hierarchy itself**". That is exactly what I wanted to know, but thanks for your answer as well.

Comment: I was also confusing myself, thinking "dimension.level.member", and not recognizing that attribute hierarchies were also hierarchies like user defined hierarchies, but now that I see they are the same, "Dimension.Hierarchy.Level", and using the attribute hierarchy twice to get leaves is what I was confused at [Period].**[Financial Year].[Financial Year]** but now I understand

Comment: @GregGalloway would you like me to edit this answer at all? 100% happy to change anything in this answer you feel I should change - I'm just a learner. p.s. would be great to see you on `mdx` questions more often sir - this forum is great to use (a lot better technology than MS's SSAS forum) but lacks some real `mdx` expert contributors like yourself. There used to be a good `mdx` overseer `FrankPI` but I think he got fed up of the lack of activity, or triviality of many of the questions, and left.

Comment: @whytheq thanks. Trying to help moderate. I would recommend you edit your answer and mention [Period].[Financial Year].CHILDREN assumes the All member is the default member and the current member in the context and won't work as intended in all contexts. Prefer [Period].[Financial Year].[All].CHILDREN or [Period].[Financial Year].[Financial Year].MEMBERS

Comment: @whytheq - He was FrankPl (l as in lemon) :P  Greg - good to have you here! This tag is rarely visited by experts like you unlike the other popular tags.

Answer (score 2):

John, I have been in a similar situation before and had posted a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25786590/2993606) on that.

The point is that it is not just a *shortcut*, but a ***risky*** practice to write `[Dim].[Attribute].CHILDREN`, since the `[All]` member, which the other answer talks about is a *scoped member* and it **can't** always be assumed that you are actually writing `[Dim].[Attribute].[All].CHILDREN` unless you write that additional `[All]`. Best to avoid it.

Also, the `[Period].[Financial Year].[Financial Year]` is **not** really a suggested way of invoking members.

The moral of the story is we definitely should try to not fall for any "shortcuts".

**EDIT: Why it is imperative to be explicit!**

The reason why `.MEMBERS` is the "suggested" way is because the SSAS engine does an additional check when you use the `.MEMBERS` function.

If a newbie MDX coder accidentally use a nonexistent hierarchy name(typo..uses `Calendar1` instead of `Calendar`, the engine surprisingly doesn't throw any error. (Pardon me for the white gaps below the following images)

[image]

But if `.MEMBERS` is used, an extra layer of checking takes place, which gives a clear and definitive error message:

[image]

Obviously, here the engine is to blame, probably this is a bug. But, we must do our part at using the tools at hand. 
In a similar way, 9 out of 10 times, `Dim.Hier.CHILDREN` syntax will work, but the fact is, it is misleading. A newbie might look at the code and assume that a hierarchy can have children. While the truth is only a member can have children.

Little off topic, but in SQL too, it is a standard `ANSI` syntax to use a semicolon at the end of a statement, but very few people actually use that syntax. The engine in turn punishes us by throwing error when semicolons are not used with some operators, like when we use CTE. SO should we make it a habit to use more semicolons? **Hell yeah!** Is it a really a shortcut? **No!**

Comment: Hello Sourav - this statement isn't correct `Also, the [Period].[Financial Year].[Financial Year] is not really a suggested way of invoking members.`. This shortcut was designed as part of the language. See this post by Mosha to see it in use: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2008/10/24/optimizing-order-of-sets-in-mdx-crossjoins.aspx

Comment: @whytheq -  Edited my answer and added some content. It's more of a best practice thing.

Comment: What is a scoped member? Having trouble finding a definition on Google. It makes sense that only a member can have children, and not a hierarchy...

But besides being "misleading" or not throwing errors, is there ever a situation where Dim.Hier.Children would return different results than Dim.Hier.All.Children? I'm just using the methodology I get when I drag fields from SSMS MDX

Comment: Did you see the example I mentioned in my question? If not, here it is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25786590/difference-in-results-while-using-children-and-allmembers-in-an-mdx-statement

Comment: What I mean is that `[All]` is not really a member. It is a calculated aggregate whose definition changes based on the members within scope(which is set by slicer or the subcube). In the example I quoted, I was using a subcube.

Comment: I don't think there would ever be a scenario where not using `All` in your query would yield different results. But after I learnt my lesson, I desist from using `.CHILDREN` on hierarchy.

Comment: @SouravA `[All]` is 100% a member - whereas `[(All)]` is a level. You say wrongly that `..[All] is not really a member`. Also you need to add in the magical semi-colon to your screen-prints.

Comment: @john as mentioned in the comment made above by Greg Galloway - if you leave out `[All]` then you will get whatever is the default member of the hierarchy - so effectively you are getting this `[Dim].[Hier].[<default_member>].CHILDREN`. In most contexts this default member is `[All]` but sometimes it may not be and then you get unexpected results.

Comment: Very helpful. I will be conscious of the default member:)

Comment: [All] is not really a *real* member. Sounds better? As per MSDN, * All member. It is a system-generated member that is not contained in the dimension table. Because the member in the (All) level is at the top of the hierarchy, the member's value is the consolidated aggregation of the values of all members in the hierarchy. The All member often serves as the default member of a hierarchy.* More on the [All] member here: http://www.bp-msbi.com/2010/02/all-member-properties-name-key-and/

Comment: @whytheq - The semicolon is not part of MDX syntax requirements, unless you are talking about the "calculations" tab in cube designer.

Comment: @SouravA I use semi-colon after all mdx and sql statements

Comment: I know. I am a fan of how neat your code looks like. Looks like a good habit you picked up from your .NET background. But don't you agree with me that there are no situations where it would cause errors(in SSMS)?

Comment: @SouravA I agree - I was just joking with you as I found it amusing that you'd stressed the use of semi-colons (sql) but in the screen-prints (mdx) there were none. I understand there is a difference (cte) but just thought it was funny.